Godaddy domain Api connection
I'm currently working on integrating GoDaddy's Domain API for dynamic subdomain registration within my project, but I've encountered a persistent issue. Despite having retrieved my API key and secret key from the GoDaddy Developer platform, I am facing an error when attempting to create a CNAME record via a POST request. The error message is as follows:
Error creating CNAME record: {
  code: 'ACCESS_DENIED',
  message: 'Authenticated user is not allowed access'
}
Error creating restaurant: Error creating CNAME record

I am developing locally and using ngrok to expose my local server. Below is the snippet of code I'm using to establish the connection:
const axios = require('axios');

const createSubdomain = async (subdomain) => {
  const domain = process.env.DOMAIN; 
  const apiKey = process.env.GODADDY_API_KEY;
  const apiSecret = process.env.GODADDY_API_SECRET;

  if (!apiKey || !apiSecret) {
    throw new Error('API key or secret is not provided in environment variables.');
  }

  const url = `https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/${domain}/records`;

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `sso-key ${apiKey}:${apiSecret}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };

  const ngrokUrl = '075c-190-8-35-73.ngrok-free.app';

  const body = [
    {
      type: 'CNAME',
      name: subdomain,
      data: ngrokUrl, 
      ttl: 600
    }
  ];

  try {
    const response = await axios.patch(url, body, { headers });
    if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
      console.log('CNAME record created successfully for:', subdomain);
      return true;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Failed to create CNAME record. Status: ${response.status}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating CNAME record:', error.response?.data || error.message);
    throw new Error('Error creating CNAME record');
  }
};

module.exports = createSubdomain;

Could you please help me identify what might be causing the "ACCESS_DENIED" error and suggest any potential fixes or configurations I might be missing? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and assistance.
Best regards,
Edwin Then
I initially set up my local development environment to integrate with GoDaddy's Domain API for dynamic subdomain registration. After obtaining the necessary API and secret keys from the GoDaddy developer platform, I expected to successfully create CNAME records by sending POST requests to the API. My goal was to dynamically register subdomains that point to an ngrok URL, which exposes my local server for testing purposes.
However, despite following the documentation and configuring the headers and request body as required, I encountered an 'ACCESS_DENIED' error indicating that my authenticated user does not have access permissions. This was unexpected, as I believed that with the correct API credentials, the request would be authorized and the CNAME records would be created without issues
I even contacted godaddy support but they could not help me

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Contacting GoDaddy.com was all I could do with this provider [they responded see below]. The procedure you are using to call the Api appears correct. Their service is not behaving like it was in March 2024.
Our long term solution for other domains hosted on GoDaddy with related api/access/automation issues was to transfer them to an environment where we felt the automation better for our situation.
Simple sanity check/clarification I think Edwin situation is like ours in making that Api call... We had shell scripts that worked for 4 years with the Api key obtained for production on godaddy.com until attempted usage on May 16 2023. We run 6x per year so might not pin the exact date when failures began.
The script did something simple for mydomain.com see below where $api_key:$api_secret are obtained from developer.godaddy.com:
curl https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/mydomain.com  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: sso-key $api_key:$api_secret"
the command started showing the error below:
{"code":"ACCESS_DENIED","message":"Authenticated user is not allowed access"}
The error is new to us. We see it (now) on https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/get. It wasn't listed before. We don't have emails, documentation or any communications from GoDaddy saying procedures or conditions for access to the API are to change. So failures occurred.
I have reached out to godaddy.com.
UPDATE 05/21/2024:
GoDaddy responded. It appears to be a change:

Hi,
We have recently updated the account requirements to access parts of our production Domains API. As part of this update, access to these APIs are now limited:

Availability API: Limited to accounts with 50 or more domains
Management and DNS APIs: Limited to accounts with 10 or more domains and/or an active Premium Discount Domain Club plan.

If you have lost access to these APIs, but feel you meet these requirements, please reply back with your account number and we will review your account and whitelist you if we have denied you access in error.
Please note that this does not affect your access to any of our OTE APIs.
If you have any further questions or need assistance with other API questions, please reach out.
Regards,
API Support Team.

